# Access database won't share

Tags: ms-access

We have an access database on a file share that has permissions for everyone in the department to access. The problem i am having is that when multiple users try accessing the database at the same time they are unable to do this. One user can open the database fine but when another user tries to simultaneously, they double click the file icon, get an hour glass for a split second and nothing happens after. We are using Server 2003 as our domain controller. All permissions have been verified on both a domain level and in the access database under tools-options-advanced and setting relevent permissions to shared and no locks. Do you know what could be causing this issue with a "dead link" when user try to open the file simulateneously?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It might help to know how many people need to access this. Depending on the number, you may want to continue trouble-shooting, or look at using the Free SQL Server Express Edition.

Comment: Is this a monolithic single-file MDB with data tables and forms/reports/etc. all in one file that you're attempting to share? If so, that's the likely source of the problem -- it needs to be split into front end (forms/reports/queries/etc.) and back end (data tables only) with links from the front end to the back end on the file server. Then you give each user a copy of the front end for each workstation.

Comment: @Oorang (i have updated my comment - sorry for the confusion) Ok here is the strangest thing. It looks like when i open the file from the shortcut and the ldb file is created, it stops me from opening any other instances of it. However if i manually open access through Start-Programs etc and browse to the location in the share drive, i can have multiple copies open at the same time. This is truly bizarre but at lease i am able to get my users to do this. It works fine also with record editing. There are no conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occasionally happens to Access databases for almost no apparent reason. Of the suggested responses by Microsoft, you are already doing the second (opening from within Access) but I believe the first provides somewhat of the answer you are looking for.

> In the target of the shortcut, include
>   the path of MSAccess.exe

According to [Microsoft Help and Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927844/en-us)

Comment: Hey Kevin
Thanks for this article. I will try this out and see how it works.

Answer (score 7):

Ignore the naysayers - Access is perfectly fine for a small number of users.  Either you have the default Access settings to open dbs exclusive which will lock out other users or there is some weird network problem.

EDIT 
- noticed you already have default shared access
- is record-level locking on?
- also try giving user full control of the shared network folder (Access needs read/write/create/delete to be able to create and delete the ldb file)

Comment: @DJ - if his department has more than a few staff, this setup will prove a constant and unrelenting pain in the neck.

Comment: Access works very well for small groups, I have a several Access databases in use for a number of years. I even have a database on a small, private website.

Comment: I have successfully implemented many Access apps with dozens of users

Comment: @Galwegian - I've upvoted both yours and DJ's answers as I think they're both useful and on-target but for different reasons.
@TT1611 - Check your backup/disaster recovery plan every month. Do a restore. If at all possible use a real DBMS like SQL Server.

Comment: You don't need DELETE permission, only read/write/change. Without DELETE, the LDB file is never deleted, but that's the way Jet before version 3.0 worked anyway. Having no delete permission for users on the folder your back end is stored in has the advantage of preventing the user from deleting your data file "accidentally."

Comment: @DWF - not sure how access behaves without DELETE permission - I know it tries to delete the ldb when the last person closes the database - point taken on the preventing accidental deletes

Answer (score 1):

When you say share permissions, do the users have full permissions? Full permissions are needed because the share file (.ldb) must be created and deleted.

Comment: No delete permission is required -- see my comment on DJ's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am just recently experiencing the same issues, only one person can open the database.  We only have 3 people accessing the same database through shorcuts on our desktop.

Now according to Microsoft we need to include the database path in our shortcut, I will tried that.  They acknowledge this problem.

Answer (score -3):

MS Access is not worth the trouble in a multi-user setup.

Your time is better spent converting the database over to a server-based RDBMS such as SQL server while you still have hair.

Believe me, you will have to do it sooner or later anyway! Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: so whats the whole point of the share feature in accces then. Arent these options desinged so that users can share across the network?

Comment: @G - that's an eight-year old document talking about Access 2000

Comment: If you're not competent in Access, you likely can't create a successful multi-user Access app. On the other hand, if you know what you're doing (as all the professional Access developers I know are), you have no difficulty with the process. Those who claim it's not possible at all clearly fall in one or the other categories, seems to me.