# How to read the same file from many computers in net?

Tags: database, ms-access

I would like to know if it is possible to read a file simultaneously from many computers that are in net. In particular:a MS Access Data Base file that will be updated (adding, deleting info) from those computers. The file must be the same for every computer and must remain updated for every computer.

This is:

```
 PC1    PC2    PC3    PC4
  |      |      |      |
  ----------------------
            |
       MS Access DB  

(PC´s are in local net)
```

I´m thinking on using **DropBox** for doing this, because it updates almost at the moment the selected file, but is not a very elegant solution.

Could you recommend me another solution?

**Notice**: I open the DB file in code. this is: programming it. The user does not browse/select the file *by hand*.

Thank you.

Comment: @pst : thank you, I will check it. What kind of limitations? What advice could you tell me about this issue. Maybe there is a more elegant solutions that my original proposition -an alternative to file sharing-

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to use a database that runs a in a client/server configuration. This isn't very practical for an *existing* access database, however -- or a database that *needs* that type of support with MS Access ;-) I wonder if there are any transparent 3rd party proxy solutions...? Anyway...

Comment: Several processes writing the same file is a sure recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Server Message Block (aka SMB aka "network shares")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) and has been part of Windows for a *very* long time (actually, it *predates* Windows ;-). Please note that there are issues when "sharing" an access database file like this.

Personally I'd recommend against this kind of access, but *it is an officially supported use-case* (fsvo supported). See the Microsoft article "[About sharing an Access database on a network](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-sharing-an-access-database-on-a-network-mdb-HP005240860.aspx)" for a good overview.

Also see [Microsoft Access Database: Ways to share an Access Database](http://accessdatabasetutorial.com/2011/06/04/microsoft-access-database-ways-to-share-an-access-database/) and [Access database won't share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893654/access-database-wont-share). "Linked tables" seem to be preferred over a monolithic design...

Happy sharing.

Answer (score 1):

While it may be *possible* to do what you are asking, the best solution would be to migrate to a real database on your network (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.).

Another alternative would be to access the Access database from a network share.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, as a requirement, by now, is that the DB must be in Access. I will try the network sharing solutions.